# Search text for all keywords in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of keywords with an integer weight associated with it.  In another table I have a table of texts.  I would like to compute the value of each text by finding the keywords and summing the weights in the text.  Is there a way to do this entirely in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you represent your texts as

```
| text_id | count | word      |
|---------+-------+-----------|
|       1 |     1 | nice      |
|       1 |     2 | weather   |
|       1 |     3 | no?       |
|       2 |     1 | Mayer     |
|       2 |     2 | Hawthorne |
|       2 |     3 | has       |
|       2 |     4 | soul      |
```

where text with ID 1 is "nice weather no?", for example, you can calculate the text scores using the keyword table

```
| keyword   | weight |
|-----------+--------|
| weather   |      2 |
| nice      |      3 |
| Hawthorne |     10 |
| soul      |      5 |
```

with

```
SELECT t.text_id AS text_id, SUM(k.weight) AS score
FROM texts t
LEFT JOIN keywords k
ON k.keyword == t.word
GROUP BY t.text_id;
```

resulting in

```
| text_id | score |
|---------+-------|
|       1 |     5 |
|       2 |    15 |
```

Comment: That is a very interesting idea.  This is almost like turning a document into a vector.  Eventually I could normalize out the words in the text table to be to indexes into a dictionary.  I would like to know if this is a common approach and if there are any drawbacks.

Comment: I just found one: need an extra column for the order of words.  UI code is also complicated by concatenating all the strings.  It looks like there will need to be some C++ code to segment out the words to build the table anyway, might as well do it on demand.  from your approach i came up with another: a big WHERE IN clause for each word in the text.